# Sqoop Oracle Hive Error

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am having a problem with the **sqoop finding my table's upper bound value**. It has to be **203** but its coming **null** as a result of which the **query (in bolded )** is wrong.

```
hduser@hduser:~$ sudo -u hdfs sqoop job --create testora -- import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.6:1521/DB --username SYSTEM -password Welcome123 --table employees --columns "emp_id,emp_name,emp_salary" --check-column "emp_id" --incremental "append" --last-value "200" --hive-table=oraemployees --hive-import --split-by "emp_id" --target-dir /user/hdfs/oraemployees;

13/04/15 17:35:46 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.

13/04/15 17:35:46 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override

13/04/15 17:35:46 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
flutura@flutura:~$ sudo -u hdfs sqoop job --exec testora10

13/04/15 17:35:51 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000

13/04/15 17:35:51 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation

13/04/15 17:35:52 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT

13/04/15 17:35:52 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM employees t WHERE 1=0

13/04/15 17:35:52 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop

13/04/15 17:35:52 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Found hadoop core jar at: /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar

13/04/15 17:35:52 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hdfs/compile/a85f9eb2e63c0150ce13f684dfab16ff/employees.jar

13/04/15 17:35:52 INFO tool.ImportTool: Incremental import based on column emp_id

13/04/15 17:35:52 INFO tool.ImportTool: **Lower bound value: 200**

13/04/15 17:35:52 INFO tool.ImportTool: **Upper bound value: null**

13/04/15 17:35:52 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of employees

13/04/15 17:35:53 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: **SELECT MIN(emp_id), MAX(emp_id) FROM employees WHERE ( emp_id > 200 AND emp_id IS NULL  )**

13/04/15 17:35:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201304151528_0010

13/04/15 17:35:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201304151528_0010

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 15

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=3881

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=109

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=72408

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=0

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=125415424

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=500

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=200998912

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=1019650048

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=0

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=109

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 7.2782 seconds (0 bytes/sec)

13/04/15 17:35:59 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.

13/04/15 17:36:00 INFO util.AppendUtils: Creating missing output directory - oraemployees10

13/04/15 17:36:00 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT

13/04/15 17:36:00 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM employees t WHERE 1=0

13/04/15 17:36:00 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.hive.TableDefWriter.getCreateTableStmt(TableDefWriter.java:177)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:175)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:394)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:455)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:233)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:288)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:182)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:221)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:230)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:239)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(emp_id), 
  MAX(emp_id) FROM employees WHERE ( emp_id > 200 AND emp_id IS NULL  )
```

This cannot return any sensible values, since you are asking for

```
emp_id IS NULL
```

so it can only ever return NULL.

Comment: The query is auto generated by sqoop. Is there anything that i can do to override this query.